# Powershell - Replacing rows in .csv with grouped items

Tags: powershell

I have the following scenario.
A .csv file containing orders. Orders with multiple items are on separate rows.
I'm grouping rows by order id and sku to perform sums on some columns prior to exporting to .csv

I have the following code below which performs the grouping and sums and can write out the results to separate .csv

What I need to do is append the original .csv file by replacing the original rows with the summed rows.
Any help greatly appreciated

For example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKZQz.jpg)

```html
$output = @()

# Import .CSV and group on amazon-order-id and sku
# Filter group to only give lines with multiple occurances of each sku per order

Import-Csv D:\Exports\Test\AMAZON\*.csv | Group-Object amazon-order-id, sku | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1} | 

# Loop through group object. Take first line of each group and place in $new variable
# Using dot notation, sum required columns and add rows to $output variable

ForEach-Object {

$new = $_.Group[0].psobject.Copy()

$new.'quantity-shipped' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object quantity-shipped -Sum).Sum
$new.'item-price' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object item-price -Sum).Sum
$new.'item-tax' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object item-tax -Sum).Sum
$new.'shipping-price' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object shipping-price -Sum).Sum
$new.'shipping-tax' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object shipping-tax -Sum).Sum
$new.'gift-wrap-price' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object gift-wrap-price -Sum).Sum
$new.'gift-wrap-tax' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object gift-wrap-tax -Sum).Sum
$new.'item-promotion-discount' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object item-promotion-discount -Sum).Sum
$new.'ship-promotion-discount' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object ship-promotion-discount -Sum).Sum

$output += $new

}

#Select all group members and export to .csv file

$output | select * | Export-Csv D:\Exports\Test\AMAZON\Import_Me.csv -not
```

Comment: If you have multiple CSV files with the same `amazon-order-id` and `sku`, how do you know which files to update?

Comment: @AdminOfThings Good point. At this stage I'm using a single .csv file despite the *.csv. I will expand the code later to cope with multiples

Comment: Could you add a sanitised (and short) example CSV for us to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to group common rows into a single row and only be left with those grouped single rows plus uncommon rows.

```
$CSVFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Exports\Test\AMAZON -File -Filter '*.csv' | Where Extension -eq '.csv'
$output = foreach ($csv in $CSVFiles) {
    $csvOutput = Import-Csv $csv.FullName
    $group = $csvOutput | Group-Object amazon-order-id, sku
    $group | Where Count -gt 1 | Foreach-Object {
        $_.Group[0].'quantity-shipped' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object quantity-shipped -Sum).Sum
        $_.Group[0].'item-price' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object item-price -Sum).Sum
        $_.Group[0].'item-tax' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object item-tax -Sum).Sum
        $_.Group[0].'shipping-price' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object shipping-price -Sum).Sum
        $_.Group[0].'shipping-tax' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object shipping-tax -Sum).Sum
        $_.Group[0].'gift-wrap-price' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object gift-wrap-price -Sum).Sum
        $_.Group[0].'gift-wrap-tax' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object gift-wrap-tax -Sum).Sum
        $_.Group[0].'item-promotion-discount' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object item-promotion-discount -Sum).Sum
        $_.Group[0].'ship-promotion-discount' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object ship-promotion-discount -Sum).Sum
    }
    $group | Foreach-Object { $_.Group[0] } # Output to variable only
    $group | Foreach-Object { $_.Group[0] } | Export-Csv $csv.FullName -NoType
}
$output
```

**Explanation:**

`$CSVFiles` is a collection of CSV files. We need to be able to target them one-by-one to know which file to update. Each file is targeted using a `foreach` loop with the current file being `$csv`.

Since `$csvOutput` is the contents of a CSV file as an array of `PSCustomObjects`, we can update each object with a `Foreach-Object` and it will be reflected back in `$csvOutput`.

`$group` is assigned the `Group-Object` output of each CSV file. Using a variable here minimizes the grouping action to only once per file. First, perform the modifications on each group where there are multiple matches. Using your logic, the first object in a grouping is modified. A `Foreach-Object` is used to go through all the groupings.

Once all modifications are done for one CSV file, `$group` is output (this includes multiple and single groupings) and only the first object in a grouping is selected (`$_.Group[0]`) using another `Foreach-Object`, which works for the single object groupings as well. That output is passed into `Export-Csv` to update the appropriate file.

`$output` lists all CSV contents after modifications.

Comment: This works as expected. Thanks very much. I did have to amend  $csvOutput = Import-Csv $csv.FullName to get the variable to populate and same with the output to file Export-Csv $csv.FullName -NoType .

Comment: Out of curiosity. $group = $csvOutput | Group-Object amazon-order-id, sku
    $group | Where Count -gt 1 | Foreach-Object {  Here you assign $group a second time to filter the Count. Is there a reason why this isn't done in one go? $group = $csvOutput | Group-Object amazon-order-id, sku | Where Count -gt 1 | Foreach-Object

Comment: Apologies I see that you already updated your code example in between me testing and updating comments. Thanks again much appreciated!

Comment: Yes. We need to output something at the end to the CSV file. So we need `$group` to contain all of the contents. The `Where Count -gt 1` is so we can just modify the common rows. But since we saved `$group` as containing all objects initially, we can easily output it later with all modifications. If we process each item in `$group`, the `$_` becomes that current item and any updates we make to it is applied to `$group`. You technically don't need `$csvoutput` at all here if you don't want to see the original CSV file contents.

Comment: Ah yes, and that is exactly the point I was missing. I knew I needed the uncommon rows as well but couldn't see how to get back to them once I had excluded them with | Where Count -gt1. I had thought of reading the file again into another group but knew there must be a better way. Very elegant thank you.